# How do I read data in C# from an XML file that has no index?

Tags: c#, xml, indexing

I am currently creating a time registry and need to sort, order and filter the data. My goal is to to input the raw data, so logging in and out of a building per day, and to output an XML file that contains a list of the times that each person was logged in per day.

I am familiar with Python, but am new to C# and XML.
My problem is, is that all examples on XML that I have found contain a structured tree as such:

```
<PurchaseOrder>
    <MyAddress>
        <FirstName>George</FirstName>
    </MyAddress>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I have tried to read and print data with XElement, XmlDocument, XmlNode and have succeeded to print all data without iterating through the lines. I have now made enough changes for nothing to work anymore. Could someone please point me in the right direction to which Xml classes or if I should use LINQ, DOM or XPath to sort and filter XML data.

```
    public void PrintData()
    {
        var fileName = "C/<user>/documents/Events.xml";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("doc", doc);

        XmlElement Data = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlAttributeCollection attrColl = Data.Attributes;
        for (int i = 0; i < attrColl.Count; i++) ;
        {
            Console.Write("{0} = ", attrColl[i].Name);
            Console.Write("{0}", attrColl[i].Value);
        }

        XElement el = XElement.Load(fileName);
        foreach (var item in el.Ancestors())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ancestors", item);
        }

        IList<XElement> indexedElements = el.Elements().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("indexedelements", indexedElements[0]);

        IEnumerable<XElement> childElements =
            from elements in el.Elements()
            select elements;
        foreach (XElement elements in childElements)
            Console.WriteLine("name", el);

    }
```

### raw data above and desired data below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Events xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EventList>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-04 15:00:00" name="mr john" action="leave"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-04 15:00:00" name="jane doe" action="leave"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-04 14:00:00" name="jane doe" action="enter"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-04 13:30:00" name="jane doe" action="leave"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-04 13:00:00" name="mr john" action="enter"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-04 12:00:00" name="jane doe" action="enter"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-03 15:00:00" name="mr john" action="leave"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-03 15:00:00" name="jane doe" action="leave"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-03 13:00:00" name="mr john" action="enter"/>
    <DATA datetime="2022-02-03 12:00:00" name="jane doe" action="enter" />
  </EventList>
</Events>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Events xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EventList>
     <DATA datetime="2022-02-04" name="mr john" totaltime="2" />
     <DATA datetime="2022-02-04" name="jane doe" totaltime="2.5" />
     <DATA datetime="2022-02-03" name="mr john" totaltime="2" />
     <DATA datetime="2022-02-03" name="jane doe" totaltime="3" />
  </EventList>
</Events>
```

Comment: Partly for my own interest, I decided to see how an XQuery solution would look - it seems an ideal use case for a "sliding window" query. I found it harder than expected, and hit a Saxon bug: you can see the details at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5283

Answer (score 1):

Try following using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Event[] events = new Event[] {
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 15:00:00"), name = "mr john", action = "leave"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 15:00:00"), name = "jane doe", action = "leave"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 14:00:00"), name = "jane doe", action = "enter"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 13:30:00"), name = "jame doe", action = "leave"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 13:00:00"), name = "mr john", action = "enter"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 12:00:00"), name = "jane doe", action = "enter"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 15:00:00"), name = "mr john", action = "leave"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 15:00:00"), name = "jane doe", action = "leave"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 13:00:00"), name = "mr john", action = "enter"},
                new Event { date = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-04 12:00:00"), name = "jane doe", action = "enter"}
            };

            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                            "<Events xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                               "<EventList>" +
                               "</EventList>" +
                            "</Events>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement eventList = doc.Descendants("EventList").First();
   
            foreach(Event evnt in events)
            {
                XElement data = new XElement("DATA", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("datetime", evnt.date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")),
                    new XAttribute("name", evnt.name),
                    new XAttribute("action", evnt.action)
                });
                eventList.Add(data);
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
  
    }
    public class Event
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string action { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little muddled. I'd stick to LINQ to XML (so `XDocument`, `XElement`, `XAttribute` etc.). You can read your XML into strongly-typed objects like this:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

var data =
    from e in doc.Descendants("DATA")
    select new
    {
        Date = (DateTime)e.Attribute("datetime"),
        Name = (string)e.Attribute("name"),
        Action = (string)e.Attribute("action")
    };
```

And you can then use this to generate your new data. I'm not entirely clear how you're mapping to this, so I've just gone with grouping by date and name and returning the count as `totaltime`. You can change to whatever logic you need - I'm mainly demonstrating how you'd create the XML:

```cs
var newData =
    from item in data
    group item.Action by new { item.Date.Date, item.Name }
    into g
    select new XElement("Data",
        new XAttribute("datetime", XmlConvert.ToString(g.Key.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")),
        new XAttribute("name", g.Key.Name),
        new XAttribute("totaltime", g.Count())
    );

var newDoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Events",
        new XElement("EventList", newData)
    ));

newDoc.Save(newFileName);
```

You can see a working demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BQPeTi).

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you very much! It is informative to see how XDocument, XElement ,Descendants and Attributes are used in a real world example. However, this answer counts the number of actions performed and does not take time into account

Comment: @Bende yes, and the answer states as such. You asked for advice on reading and writing XML, which is what the focus here is. You have `g` (which contains all the times and actions for a specific person on a specific day), you should be able to write whatever your logic is to determine the value you require.

Comment: That is true. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For information, here is an XQuery solution.

```
  <Result> {
       for sliding window $window in reverse($input//DATA)
                    start $enter when $enter/@action = "enter"
                    end $leave when $leave/@action = "leave" 
                               and $leave/@name = $enter/@name
       let $entry := xs:dateTime(translate($enter/@datetime, ' ', 'T'))
       let $departure := xs:dateTime(translate($leave/@datetime, ' ', 'T')) 
       let $duration := $departure - $entry
       let $tripDate := xs:date($entry)
       let $tripName := string($enter/@name)
       group by $tripDate, $tripName
       let $totalDuration := sum($duration)
       order by $tripDate descending, $tripName
       return <DATA datetime="{$tripDate}" 
                    name="{$tripName}" 
                    totaltime="{$totalDuration div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H')}"/> 
  } </Result>
```

I have to confess I found this quite difficult, if only because I found a Saxon bug along the way! But I thought it might be of interest to others.

I've added it to the XQuery test suite as test SlidingWindowExpr562. The combination of windowing, grouping, and sorting is rather more complex than any of the existing test cases.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. Great job! It looks like it does what it is supposed to do. Can I run this from within Visual Studio?

Comment: I've no idea if Visual Studio can run XQuery 3.1, sorry. It would have to be some third-party plug-in of some kind.